# Converting M-YY to Datetime using Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

### I have data frame with Month field having following values
April-20
May-20
June-20

--

pandas shows this as object. How can I convert this column to Date?

Answer (score 0):

[`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas-to-datetime) with [format string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Month': ["April-20", "May-20", "June-20"]})
df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month'], format="%B-%y")

print(df)
print()
print(df.dtypes)
```

Output:

```
       Month
0 2020-04-01
1 2020-05-01
2 2020-06-01

Month    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```